# How to read a brotli compressed string?

Tags: java, http, jsoup, brotli

I'm getting a brotli compressed json string from a website. I want to decompress and read it.

When I use input stream from response, I'm able to read it properly using

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BrotliInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent())));
```

Whereas when I have saved the response in a String and reading it

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BrotliInputStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(responseAsString, "UTF-8"))));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

I'm getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Brotli stream decoding failed
    at org.brotli.dec.BrotliInputStream.read(BrotliInputStream.java:167)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.brotli.test.BrotliStringTest.main(BrotliStringTest.java:113)
Caused by: org.brotli.dec.BrotliRuntimeException: Unused space
    at org.brotli.dec.Decode.readHuffmanCodeLengths(Decode.java:226)
    at org.brotli.dec.Decode.readHuffmanCode(Decode.java:296)
    at org.brotli.dec.HuffmanTreeGroup.decode(HuffmanTreeGroup.java:53)
    at org.brotli.dec.Decode.readMetablockHuffmanCodesAndContextMaps(Decode.java:528)
    at org.brotli.dec.Decode.decompress(Decode.java:621)
    at org.brotli.dec.BrotliInputStream.read(BrotliInputStream.java:161)
    ... 8 more
```

Edit 1:

I tried using Jsoup and found that it supports only Gzipped streams and doesn't support BrotliInputStream in its HttpConnection class. Any pointers on this?

Comment: But why are your two example of using `BrotliInputStream` not identical?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, in one example, I'm reading directly from `InputStream` returned by the `HttpResponse` whereas in another example I'm first converting the string to `InputStream` to be fed to `BrotliInputStream`. This is not working when I'm trying with string specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had resolved it like this:-

```
import org.brotli.dec.BrotliInputStream;

if(response.getLastHeader("content-encoding").getValue().equals("br")) { // check if getting brotli compressed stream
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BrotliInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent())));
}
else {
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
}
```

This worked for brotli/non-brotli(gzipped, etc) streams.